# Como pegar o valor de um Spinner e continuar o formulario

Tags: android, android-layout

Boa tarde, eu tenho um formulario simples no meu app android, onde o usuario escreve nome e cadastra um alerta, mas no campo frequencia do alerta eu inseri um spinner(selectbox do android) com opções de numeros que são strings.

```
txtFrequencia.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);

    List<String> frequencia = new ArrayList<String>();
    frequencia.add("2");
    frequencia.add("4");
    frequencia.add("6");
    frequencia.add("8");
    frequencia.add("10");
    frequencia.add("12");
    frequencia.add("24");


    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, frequencia);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    txtFrequencia.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Essa é a parte onde declaro o spinner, mas o problema esta acontecendo na minha classe que cadastra no banco de dados, não sei ao certo o que inserir nela, eu estou usando getOnItemSelectedListener() para tentar pegar o valor mas não está funcionando, segue o codigo:

```
 private long loadType() {
    Type type = new Type();
    millisIdentificador = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    type.setContent("Alerta;" + String.valueOf(millisIdentificador) + ";" + txtNomeAlerta.getText().toString()
            + ";" + (btnTodoDia.isChecked() ? 1 : 0) + ";" + (btnFimdeSemana.isChecked() ? 1 : 0)
            + ";" + Integer.parseInt(txtFrequencia.getOnItemSelectedListener().toString()) + ";"
            + Integer.parseInt(txtQuantComprimidos.getText().toString()) + ";"
            + Integer.parseInt(txtQuantDias.getText().toString()));
    type.setComentarCard(0);
    type.setCompartilharCard(0);
    type.setCurtirCard(0);
    return dataStoreType.addType(type);
}
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como posso fazer para colocar o valor correto da posição do spinner.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, ao invés de `getOnItemSelectedListener()` use `getSelectedItem()` que retorna um objeto, ou `getSelectedItemPosition()` que retorna a posição da lista do item que foi escolhido pelo usuário.

Exemplo:

```
int posicao = txtFrequencia.getSelectedItemPosition();
String itemSelecionado = frequencia.get(posicao);
```

Espero que tenha ajudado!